# Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Tags: php, oracle, iis, oracle-call-interface, instantclient

I have the next lines uncommented (in my php.ini):

```
extension=php_oracle.dll 
extension=php_oci8.dll
```

And I downloaded this file `instantclient-basiclite-nt-11.2.0.2.0.zip` and unzipped and put that on drive D...

I am using Windows XP

I set environment variable like this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH     C:\instantclient_11_2:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
ORACLE_HOME     C:\instantclient_11_2
```

But when I execute `oci_connect()` function, I see this error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in ...

and i found this warnings on erroeLog file:

> [29-Dec-2011 00:36:39] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\php\ext\php_oci8.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>    in Unknown on line 0
>
> [29-Dec-2011 00:36:39] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\php\ext\php_oracle.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

Comment: What messages do the CLI version or Apache output? Also what do the log files or the system log thingy say?

Comment: This should help for the above error!! [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39770392/3973543)

Answer (score 4):

Things to check:

- You don't need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` nor `ORACLE_HOME`. However, you need to add `D:\instantclient_11_2` to the `PATH` environmental variable and restart the computer so changes apply.
- Before configuring PHP, check that your Oracle client libraries actually work (for instance, try to connect with SQL Developer).
- Comment out the `extension=php_oracle.dll`. It belongs to the old and deprecated Oracle extension.
- Double check that the `php_oci8.dll` file is really at `c:\php\ext\php_oci8.dll`?

Comment: @afsane - Then it's obvious: it it doesn't work standalone, it can't work under PHP.

Comment: I have the same problem, and find commented the php_oci8.dll in ini file and see beside another comment like this: "Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client". it's referred to your first point of things to check? What's teh difference using instantclient or uncomment the php_oci8.dll in ini file?

Comment: @Andrea_86 - The same difference that exists between using PHP and using Apache: different stuff, both required.

Answer (score 2):

Did you restart apache after putting the `php_oci8.dll` file in your `php/ext` directory?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to the php.in file that point to the location of extensions, should know where they are located, but normally in php folder.

`extension_dir = C:\xampp\php\ext   ;`this is for me using xampp, be wise.

It worked for me. The problem is with accessing the extensions and has nothing to do with oracle libraries.