# PHP, oci driver

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface

i want to enable connections to oracle db but everything i do is not working:

my `phpinfo()` is not showing seperate section for oci8 but at start of `phpinfo` there is

```
Architecture    x86
Configure Command   cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build"
"--disable-isapi"
"--enable-debug-pack"
"--without-mssql"
"--without-pdo-mssql"
"--without-pi3web"
"--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient10\sdk,shared"
"--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient10\sdk,shared"
"--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient11\sdk,shared"
"--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/"
"--enable-com-dotnet=shared"
"--with-mcrypt=static"
"--disable-static-analyze"
"--with-pgo"
```

i have downloaded instantclient 11_2 and modified windows `path`, added at the end : `C:\xampp\oracle_driver\` and `php.ini` looks like this:

```
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
extension=php_oci8.dll
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll
```

Comment: Try the steps listed in [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29515269/3775731).