# can not load oci8 -> Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface, oci8

I want to connect to my oracle database, but i have a problem with function oci_connect. i have tried to uncomment this:

```
extension=php_oci8.dll
```

but, still have an error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\db.php on line 71

But, when i check in phpinfo(), oci8 still not loaded and i can not connect to my oracle database. i already restart my apache. How i fix this problem ? Canyou help me?

Thank you..

Comment: Is an Oracle client installed? Have you read the [requirements](http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.requirements.php) and followed the [installation](http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php) instructions?

Comment: of course yes. previously i use xampp version 1.6.4 and it works fine. now i upgrade my xampp into version 5.5.30 but i got that error. can you help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Check that `php_oci8.dll` exists in the `ext` folder.  Check the `php_errors.log` file for startup errors and edit your question to include any information from there.

Comment: Also, try following the steps in a [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29515269/3775731) of mine.

Comment: php_oci8.dll exists in ext folder. when i cek the php_error_log, i got this : "[10-Dec-2015 10:01:14 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found." . why can not load the php_oci8.dll ? whereas php_oci8.dll is existing in ext folder .. confused~~

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 16.04, using PHP 5.6, with 64bit os, try this:

Install the packages:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-dev build-essential php-pear libaio1
```

Download the latest version of the packages from:

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html
```

Search for these packages, according with the latest version:

```
oracle-instantclientXX.X-basic-XX.X.X.X.X-X.x86_64.rpm
oracle-instantclientXX.X-devel-XX.X.X.X.X-X.x86_64.rpm
```

Converting packages:

```
sudo apt-get install alien
sudo alien oracle-instantclientXX.X-basic-XX.X.X.X.X-X.x86_64.rpm
sudo alien oracle-instantclientXX.X-devel-XX.X.X.X.X-X.x86_64.rpm
```

Installing:

```
sudo dpkg -i oracle-instantclientXX.X-basic_XX.X.X.X.X-X_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i oracle-instantclientXX.X-devel_XX.X.X.X.X-X_amd64.deb
```

Installing oci8:

```
sudo pecl install oci8-2.0.12

*Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/20131226/oci8.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/oci8-2.0.12
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=oci8.so" to php.ini*
```

Add the extension to php:

```
sudo gedit /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini
```

add the extension:

```
extension=oci8.so
```

Restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

In `php.ini` ensure that you enable the correct OCI extension (11g), like this:

```
;extension=php_oci8.dll      ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client
```

As long as you've got [Oracle 11gR2 or greater client libraries](http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.requirements.php) correctly installed you should now be able to run:

```
C:\>php --ri oci8
```

And get the result:

```
oci8

OCI8 Support => enabled
Version => 1.4.10
Revision => $Id: b0984d94e17f7c099470cd0a9404259f2a59da04 $
Active Persistent Connections => 0
Active Connections => 0
Oracle Run-time Client Library Version => 11.2.0.3.0
Oracle Instant Client Version => 11.2
Temporary Lob support => enabled
Collections support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
oci8.max_persistent => -1 => -1
oci8.persistent_timeout => -1 => -1
oci8.ping_interval => 60 => 60
oci8.privileged_connect => Off => Off
oci8.statement_cache_size => 20 => 20
oci8.default_prefetch => 100 => 100
oci8.old_oci_close_semantics => Off => Off
oci8.connection_class => no value => no value
oci8.events => Off => Off
```

To check your Oracle client is installed correctly (i.e., in your environment `PATH` variable) you can run:

```
C:\>where oci*
```

You should get a result like this:

```
C:\instantclient_11_2\oci.dll
C:\instantclient_11_2\oci.sym
C:\instantclient_11_2\ocijdbc11.dll
C:\instantclient_11_2\ocijdbc11.sym
C:\instantclient_11_2\ociw32.dll
C:\instantclient_11_2\ociw32.sym
```

Comment: when i run the command  C:\>php --ri oci8, i got this, "php is not recognizedas an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." and i run C:\>where  oci*, the result like this: `C:\DevSuiteHome_1\BIN\oci.dll
C:\DevSuiteHome_1\BIN\ocijdbc10.dll
C:\DevSuiteHome_1\BIN\ociw32.dll.

Comment: i use oracle client 10g, and the folder'd name is DevSuiteHome.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the offcial link for me Oracle

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/technote-php-instant-084410.html

Here is what worked with Xammp

1.uncomment extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client if you are using 11g (in php.ini)

2.add   AddHandler fcgid-script .php to httpd.conf

3.Download the FastCGI component mod_fcgid-2.3.6-win32-x86.zip from [httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#mod_fcgid](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#mod_fcgid)

4.Unzip it to the installed Apache 2.2 directory. The C:\xamp\apache\modules  directory should now have mod_fcgid.so and mod_fcgid.pdb files.

5.Download the "Instant Client Package - Basic" for Windows from the OTN Instant Client page. Because PHP is 32 bit, use the 32 bit version of Instant Client.

Unzip the Instant Client files to C:\instantclient_11_2

Edit the Windows PATH environment setting and add C:\instantclient_11_2. For example, on Windows XP, follow Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Environment Variables and edit PATH in the System variables list.

Commonly you need to reboot Windows so the new environment is correctly set.

that worked for me all the best

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [RO_engineer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3885376/ro-engineer)'s answer of installing x86 files of Oracle insta client rather than x64 version. It resolved my issue, may be that can help you too.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27177616/289587

[Download Instant Client for Microsoft Windows (32-bit)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html)