# PHP with OCI8 Oracle connection on Windows 10 x64 and Windows Server 2008 x64

Tags: php, oci8

I am struggling with the setup of an Oracle database connection in Windows x64

My system:

- Windows 10 x64 as client PC
- Windows Server 2008 x64 as DBServer in the local network
- PHP 7.2 TS Windows x64 installation Oracle Database
- 11.2 Oracle Database Client (present installation of 2014 do not now version, must be a x64 because it runs on server 64 bit)

Other Connections:

- SQL Plus connection is working on server and on client PC SQL
- Developer is connected to Database on server and works on client PC too.

Just the connection over PHP to the Database is making huge problems.

I know it is a x64 system so I installed the php 7.2 TS for windows x64.
I do not even come to connect to the Oracle Database Client... because the installation of the oci8.dll extension is failing.

What I did so far:
I uncommented the extentinos in the php.ini: OCI8.dll and the OCI8_11g.dll and put it into the php/ext directory.
I set an absolute path to the ext-folder in php.ini

When trying to load php in the command prompt with extention oci8 or oci8_11g enabled it says:
[path to the ext] not a Windows32 application or ...dll not found - but the directory is correct and the ddl-file is there.

I tried to set up an apache server from apachelounge build x64 and it is running. PHP7 is installed as an implemented apache module and the oci8 is enabled. But still it does give me the PHP warning message of [path to the ext] not ...dll not found.
I do not know what to do now. My windows 10 is a new installation. I did not change the system variables. PHP is just not taking the extesion.

You can find the phpinfo of my client PC uploaded as a screenshot here:
https://ibb.co/iPJ4W7

Any suggestions?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to download the Oracle Instant Client, unzip it somewhere, and add that location to your `Path` System variable.

Comment: It is already installed on the server. There I tried the same again and again. But not working. Now I install the client on my client PC and add the path. I will let you know.

Comment: You will need to figure out what version you have installed because you need specific Visual Studio Redistributable. [v12.2.0.1.0 requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Redistributable](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to undefined function oci\_connect, php\_oci8\_12c.dll, windows 8.1, php5.6.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257894/call-to-undefined-function-oci-connect-php-oci8-12c-dll-windows-8-1-php5-6-6)