# Oracle database Connection issue in php

Tags: php, oracle

I have a database `IP:10.21.30.178` on `port:1525` with credentials `user:FUNREAD`, `pass:clock24` and `service name:DRFUNPD1`.

I am trying to connect from my machine(`10.21.30.220`) and writing below code to connect.

```
<?php

    // Connects to the XE service (i.e. database) on the "localhost" machine
    $conn = oci_connect('FUNREAD', 'clock24', '10.6.8.51:1525/DRFUNPD1');
    if (!$conn) {
        $e = oci_error();
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM employees');
    oci_execute($stid);

    echo "<table border='1'>\n";
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
        echo "<tr>\n";
        foreach ($row as $item) {
            echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) :    "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";

?>
```

but getting below error..

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\bkash\pending.php on line 4

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635881/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-oci-connect  ,  And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478387/call-to-undefined-function-oci-connect

Answer (score 0):

According to the fatail error message, you don't have the OCI8 extension installed:

http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php