# Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in Wamp

Tags: php, oracle, function, wamp

There are similar topics in here but the solutions did not fix my problem.

My OS is Windows 7-64 bit

I use Wampserver 2.5-64 bit

I downloaded instantclient_12_1 64 bit and put it into the D:/ directory

I added the PATH which shows the directory of the instant client.(To the system)

I delete ";" characters in php.ini file(I am using 11g oracle environment)

```
;extension=php_oci8.dll      ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client
```

I can see OCI definitions when I look at the phpinfo() in localhost

I restarted the pc after I made changes

I restarted the wampserver after I made changes

I tried many ways and advices to come up with the problem but they did not fix the problem

Comment: May this links help u

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478387/call-to-undefined-function-oci-connect

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635881/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-oci-connect

Comment: I examined these links but they did not fix my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the 3 day, I found my fault. When I describe PATH in the "Environment Variables" menu, I add the "PATH" to "User Variables" part, not to "System Variables" part. 
The error was that simple and it costs me 3 day, pay attention!